# Print method content in PHP

Tags: php, decoder

```
protected function _return()
{
   return 'something';
}
```

How to print content of method? I would like to echo `return 'something';` as string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do such a thing as getting the source-code of a method, from a running-code.

You'll have to *cheat* :

- Find out in which PHP file this method is
- Open that file
- Parse it

  - using regex or stuff like that might be a way...
  - or you could work with the [**Tokenizer Functions**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php) -- a better way to manipulate PHP code !

Comment: That won't help me, cause i have encoded php file. When i use Reflection, i can get part of that class, but not method source.
Thx for anwser.

Comment: @Lrr: that's important information, you might want to say that in your questions.  Most of us don't use encoded source code, so mention explicitly that it's encoded and how...

Comment: @Lrrr oh ; sorry about that ^^ As @ircmaxell told, you should edit your wuestion to say that, because encoded PHP files are quite rare, and not that much used

Comment: Do'h. Sorry for that, didn't know if that's important :/